# How to implement rounding in BUGS in a survey context?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, survey, bugs, jags

In a traditional filtering context, you'd analyse polls coming in with something like

```
mu[i] <- alpha[date[i]]
prec[i]<- SampleSize[i]/(alpha[date[i]]*(1-alpha[date[i]])
y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i],prec[i])
```

If the surveys are observed with rounding, this *usually* won't make a difference. But I'm in a situation where it does. What would be a good way to handle the observations being rounded in BUGS code?

Comment: How exactly is rounding applied to survey results?  Aren't they always (integral) counts of responses?

Comment: I get rounded survey proportions. IE, 8%, 9%, etc.

Comment: Do you have the sample sizes at least?  Or *only* the proportions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like:

```
mu[i] <- alpha[date[i]]
prec[i]<- SampleSize[i]/(alpha[date[i]]*(1-alpha[date[i]])
e[i] ~ dunif(-0.5,0.5)
mu.round[i] <- mu[i] + e[i]
y[i] ~ dnorm(mu.round[i],prec[i])
```

would do the job.  The `e[i]` represent the difference between the observed (rounded) and true value of `y[i]`.

What we'd like to do, for clarity, is adjust the observation by:

```
y.true[i] <- y[i] - e[i]
y.true[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], prec[i])
```

which certainly won't work in JAGS, but may in BUGS (which I don't have).  Instead, I'm adding `e[i]` to the right hand side of both lines of the above, which means it gets added to `mu[i]`, and this allows us to work with the observed data directly.

Answer (score 3):

No promises about the computational efficiency of this solution, but the best way to take into account rounding to the nearest integer in JAGS is to use the dinterval "distribution".  The JAGS manual includes this passage:

> The dinterval distribution represents interval-censored data. It has
>   two parameters: t the original continuous variable, and c[], a vector
>   of cut points of length M, say. If X ∼ dinterval(t, c) then X=0 if t <
>   c[1]; X=m if c[m] ≤ t < c[m+1] for 1 ≤ m < M; X=M if c[M] ≤ t.

Assuming your polls are rounded to the nearest integer, you want to form a vector of cutpoints "roundingcutpoints" with values 0, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, ..., 99.5,
100.  Then you model t as if it was the continuous polling data.  So, modifying your code:

```
mu[i] <- alpha[date[i]]
prec[i] <- SampleSize[i]/(alpha[date[i]]*(1-alpha[date[i]])
ystar[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i],prec[i])
y[i] ~ dinterval(ystar[i],roundingcutpoints)
```